# Failed to connect to server in ssis integrationservices in C# upon deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssis

I have this code

```
    var connectionString = "Data Source=" + servername + ";Initial Catalog=" + databasename + ";Integrated Security=True";
            var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            var integrationServices = new IntegrationServices(connection);   // ERROR HERE. Failed to connect to server.

            var package = integrationServices
                .Catalogs["SSISDB"]
                .Folders["MyFolder"]
                .Projects["MyProject"]
                .Packages["MyPackage.dtsx"];

            long executionIdentifier = package.Execute(true, null);

            ExecutionOperation eo = integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"].Executions[executionIdentifier];
            while(!eo.Completed)
            {
                eo.Refresh();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
```

During development, no error is encountered but when I web deploy it, error occurs when I instantiate integrationServices like

```
    var integrationServices = new IntegrationServices(connection);
```

It is saying "Failed to connect to server". I know the error because when I console.log the error in my browser, it says so. So something is preventing me to connect my integrationservices.

Can anyone give me an idea on this? Thanks.

edited:

I already enabled allow remote connections

[image]

Comment: Does the SSISDB exist on the target server?

Comment: Yes, it is now on the target deploy server. But it's working on development server, where my visual studio resides.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a case of either a bad connection string or a SQL Server which doesn't allow 1433 port connections.

do the following:

1. wrap your whole code under a try catch
2. on error, try to display/log the `connectionString` variable value.

once you have that, either it'll show as an incorrect value. (possibly because the Dts variables or the source of your servername/databasename variable values are not set) OR the Sql server is not allowing remote connections. (you need to open up the ports)